# Upper bound on the diameter of a convex lattice n-gon with a given area

Tags: discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, computational-geometry, lattice-polytopes

Given the area $A$ of ​​a strictly convex polygon with $n$ vertices with integer Cartesian coordinates, there are usually several non-equivalent polygons. The relationship between the area, the number of vertices and the number of internal grid points is described by Pick's theorem. [Castryck](https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00454-011-9376-2) calculated an enumeration of all polygons up to 30 interior points. Of special interest is the case that the polygon has the smallest possible area for the respective $n$. See [A070911](https://oeis.org/A070911) for more information. Up to now, [various calculation methods](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/253633/the-smallest-area-of-a-convex-grid-polygon) confirm the terms of A070911. The [easy-to-find polygons](https://oeis.org/A321693/a321693_1.pdf) have a near-circular or elliptical shape with semi-axes that are not too different. However, my own program also produces polygons of a given, conjecturally minimal, area, which have an extreme needle shape, i.e. with a very large [diameter](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonDiameter.html).

Is there an upper limit for the diameter $D^2$ or similarly for the length of the longest polygon side as a function of $n$ and polygon area $A$?

As clarified by Anton Petrunin in the comment, one can create polygons of arbitrarily large diameter from smaller polygons by a shear transformation. Excluding these trivially generated polygons, is the diameter still unbounded?

### Example

#### $n=15$

A polygon of proven minimum area $A = {103}/2$ and squared diameter $D^{2} = 82$ is given by the following vertex coordinates:

```
(7,1),(8,1),(9,2),(10,4),(10,5),(9,7),(8,8),(6,9),(5,9),(3,8),(2,7),(1,5),(1,4),(2,3),(4,2)
```

[image: 2*area=103,D^2=82]

$A = 103/2$, $D^2=1289$

```
(35,1),(36,1),(33,2),(26,4),(22,5),(13,7),(8,8),(2,9),(1,9),(3,8),(6,7),(13,5),(17,4),(22,3),(28,2)
```

[image: 2*area=103, D^2=1289]

$A = 103/2$, $D^2=10114$

```
(0,0),(1,1),(11,12),(20,22),(37,41),(45,50),(60,67),(67,75),(66,74),(55,62),(45,51),(36,41),(28,32),(13,15),(6,7)
```

Step 5 in grid lines.
[image: 2*area=103, D^2=10114]

Comment: Wait, your question is $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$-invariant, so there is no bound on diameter or longest side.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin: The shearing thing is of course correct and also the reason why my search program, which knows nothing about the transformation, finds solutions with ever larger diameters. Unfortunately, I didn't ask the question in the form of whether the diameter is also unbounded for polygons that were not created by shearing. Can I still ask?